# Is it correct to say "I lay on the ring and it left a mark on my skin"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When you lie on something hard and small like a ring or a a key, that area of your skin gets concave a bit, but not convex. If the skin gets convex, it is swollen. But, the skin gets concave when you lie on something for a long time.

[image]

**What is the common word to say it?**

For example, *I lay on the ring and it left a mark (concavity) on my skin*

Comment: **I lied** means "I told a falsehood."  You mean **I lay** on the ring.  Don't worry, though - even native speakers get confused about lie/lay/lied/laid/lain!

Comment: There is a definition of an ambassador that goes "Someone sent to lie abroad for their country" Lie has two possible meanings in this case. 1) to tell falsehoods 2) to reside or live.

Comment: The picture looks like stretch marks, not ring imprints.

Comment: Whatever answers come, it's worth noting that there isn't a common term for this in English. You might say, "*...a **mark** on your skin from lying on a ring*", but "mark" is a very generic word, not specific to this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way of saying it is

> I lay on the ring and it left an indentation in my skin.

An **indentation** is a concave mark. You could also use the word **impression** with a similar meaning

Comment: @Tom These are good suggestions; even "mark" by itself explains the situation. [This comic strip](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1990/03/25) manages to explain the phenomenon simply by describing the shape of the mark ("corduroy lines" = "indentations caused by the ridged lines in corduroy fabric," and inspiring Calvin's dream of waffles)

Comment: Can I use "dent"? for example, "**I lay on the ring and it left a dent in my skin.**"

Comment: @Tom We typically only use "dent" for metal or highly rigid objects that permanently deform. Using it with to describe part of yourself sounds comedic, as if you now have a permanent crater on your body. It's certainly not a normal way of speaking.